# How to mantain focus on Whatsapp Web in WebDriver Edge to not lose the "Online" tag?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, whatsapp

I am using `WebDriver` on Edge (although open to using any explorer) to manage some tests on Whatsapp Web.

I have a situation where Whatsapp Web loses focus if I don't move my mouse, and for example, things like the "Online" tag do not appear/disappear, even if the other user is online.

I tried using `ActionChains` with `actions.move_by_offset(100, 50)` to simulate mouse movement or execute javascript code with `driver.execute_script('window.focus();')`, but it does not work. It seems I cannot maintain the "online" tag on the screen of another user if I don't manually move the pointer (basically activating focus).

This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains



# Path to your Microsoft Edge WebDriver executable
driver_path = 'THISISYOURPATH'


options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

# Initialize the Edge WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Edge()

# Open WhatsApp Web
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

# Wait for the user to scan QR code and log in
input('Press Enter after scanning QR code and logging in...')

def get_online_status():
    try:
        # Wait for the element to be visible on the page
        online_status_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@title="en línea" or @title="escribiendo..."]'))
        )
        online_status = online_status_element.text
        return online_status
    except:
        return "Status not found"



# CSV file setup
csv_file_path = 'online_status_log.csv'
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Timestamp'])


try:
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = i+1
        online = get_online_status()
        print(f'Online Status: {online}. Test {i}')

        if online.lower() == 'en línea' or online.lower() == 'escribiendo...':
            # Log the timestamp to the CSV file
            with open(csv_file_path, 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                csv_writer.writerow([datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), online])

         # Execute a JavaScript scroll on the page to trigger updates
        
        #driver.execute_script('window.focus();')
        # Create an ActionChains object
        actions = ActionChains(driver)

        if i % 2 == 0:
            actions.move_by_offset(100, 50)
        else:
            actions.move_by_offset(-100, -50)
        time.sleep(2)  # Check every 2 seconds

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping")
    # Close the browser when interrupted
    driver.quit()
```

Any suggestion? Is it an Edge configuration problem?
Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your code is correct and that the only thing that you need is to look active, you can use another module to control the mouse and keyboard called pyautogui.

If not installed, just run this:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

After installation, you can use the functions to move the mouse and keyboard. Here is a example of it moving the mouse:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import random

coordinate, coordinate1 = pyautogui.size() # Gets the coordinates of the screen
try:
  while True:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 2)) # Waits a specific time between those integers for a more human experience
    divisionNumber = random.randint(2, 3) # This line also gets a random number between those integers that is used to be divided from the coordinates for a even better human experience
    pyautogui.moveTo(coordinate / divisionNumber, coordinate1 / divisionNumber) # Moves the mouse to the coordinates divided by the divisionNumber variable
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Code interrupted")
```

That line of code makes human mouse moves and stops at KeyboardInterrupt.

If the code is not doing what you expected, you can use the pyautogui module to also automate keyboard action. If the module is not doing what you expect, use another module. This module may not be what you use but it works with me, is made specifially for the mouse and keyboard and is easier to implement.